# loops in R, finding the mean for one column depends on another column

Tags: r, loops, mean

So my test  data looks like this:

```
   structure(list(day = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L
), Left = c(0.25, 0.33, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.33, 0.5, 0.33, 0.5, 0), 
    Left1 = c(NA, NA, 0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.33, 0.1, 0.33, 0.5, 0), 
    Middle = c(0, 0, 0.3, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.3, 0.33, 0, 0), Right = c(0.25, 
    0.33, 0.3, 0.5, 0.25, 0.33, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.25), Right1 = c(0.5, 
    0.33, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.75), Side = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("L", "R"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("day", 
"Left", "Left1", "Middle", "Right", "Right1", "Side"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

or this:

```
day Left Left1 Middle Right Right1 Side
   1 0.25    NA   0.00  0.25   0.50    R
   1 0.33    NA   0.00  0.33   0.33    R
   2 0.00  0.00   0.30  0.30   0.30    R
   2 0.00  0.50   0.00  0.50   0.00    R
   2 0.25  0.25   0.25  0.25   0.00    L
   3 0.33  0.33   0.00  0.33   0.00    L
```

I would like to write a loop to find the standard error and average value for each day on the chosen side..

Ok.. So far I have this code:

```
td<-read.csv('test data.csv')

IDs<-unique(td$day)  

se<-function(x) sqrt(var(x)/length(x))

for (i in 1:length (IDs)) {


day.i<-which(td$day==IDs[i])   
td.i<-td[day.i,]

if(td$Side=='L'){ 
side<-cbind(td.i$Left + td.i$Left1)
}else{
side<-cbind(td.i$Right + td.i$Right1)
}

mean(side)
se(side)

print(mean)
print(se)

}
```

But I am getting error messages like this

Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Obviously, I am also not getting the print out of means for each day.. Does anyone know why?

also working on things here:   http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/27187-Writing-a-mean-loop..-(literally)

Comment: To be clear: in the real data, will there be more than one row for each day?

Comment: yes.. each day has several rows

Comment: What if there is no preference? e.g. two "R" and two "L" for any given day

Comment: For each day there are several rows of entry.. Each row is independent... For example.. If on day 2 there are two that choose right and one left.. I would want to find the average of the three..   I would bind the right and right1 for the 'R' side and I would bind the Left and Left1 for the 'L' side and find the average of those three...  Then I would have an average value spent on chosen side per day..   Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your data into a list and work with that instead:

First, split up your data into a list according to `Side`, subsetting the relevant columns along the way.

```
td = split(td, td$Side)
NAMES = names(td)
td = lapply(1:length(td),
            function(x) td[[x]][c(1, grep(NAMES[x],
                                          names(td[[x]])))])
names(td) = NAMES
td
# $L
#   day Left Left1
# 5   2 0.25  0.25
# 6   3 0.33  0.33
# 7   3 0.50  0.10
# 8   4 0.33  0.33
# 9   4 0.50  0.50
# 
# $R
#    day Right Right1
# 1    1  0.25   0.50
# 2    1  0.33   0.33
# 3    2  0.30   0.30
# 4    2  0.50   0.00
# 10   4  0.25   0.75
```

Then, use `lapply` and `aggregate` to apply whatever functions you want to your data.

```
lapply(1:length(td), 
       function(x) aggregate(list(td[[x]][-1]), 
                             list(day = td[[x]]$day), mean))
# [[1]]
#   day  Left Left1
# 1   2 0.250 0.250
# 2   3 0.415 0.215
# 3   4 0.415 0.415
# 
# [[2]]
#   day Right Right1
# 1   1  0.29  0.415
# 2   2  0.40  0.150
# 3   4  0.25  0.750
```

Comment: I don't understand the negative vote. (Did my best to counter it.)

Comment: @DWin, thanks. I didn't either. But then again, I'm not sure that I totally understand the question either!

Answer (score 0):

Still not entirely sure if I understand (that is if you want mean and SE for both Left and Left 1 or some sort of combination like sum).  This is how I interpreted your question:

```
FUN <- function(dat, side = "L") {
    DF <- split(dat, dat$Side)[[side]]
    ind <- if(side=="L") 2:3 else 5:6
    stderr <- function(x) sqrt(var(x)/length(x))
    meanNse <- function(x) c(mean=mean(x), se=stderr(x))
    OUT <- aggregate(DF[, ind], list(DF[, 1]),  meanNse)  
    names(OUT)[1] <- "day"
    return(OUT)
}

#test it
FUN(td)
FUN(td, "R")
```

Which yields:

```
> FUN(td)
  day Left.mean Left.se Left1.mean Left1.se
1   2     0.250      NA      0.250       NA
2   3     0.415   0.085      0.215    0.115
3   4     0.415   0.085      0.415    0.085
> FUN(td, "R")
  day Right.mean Right.se Right1.mean Right1.se
1   1       0.29     0.04       0.415     0.085
2   2       0.40     0.10       0.150     0.150
3   4       0.25       NA       0.750        NA
```

Comment: I just need the mean and SE for the chose side.. So if td$side == 'R' then I need the mean for cbind(Right + Right1), if the td$side=='L' then I need the mean for cbind(Left + Left1) for each day...

Comment: This is helpful, I would like to somehow write and 'If, then' statement to find the mean  of 'Left' total and 'Right' total only if that was the chosen side.

Comment: This works, but you have to modify the function for each different function you want to run. I decided to split the data up into a list instead.